# postMessage cross-domain communication example

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, postmessage

I'm trying to communicate from a website that is displayed in an iframe to the parent page containing the iframe with postMessage. Both pages need to be from different domains. I've built a quick example using jsfiddle and codepen (adapted from this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bmknight/A7YfK/), but the messages don't seem to be arriving. I'm guessing I'm not selecting the parent correctly when I try to invoke postMessage - can anyone give me a hint?

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/Megahra/pen/yLYWzab
[image: Screenshot of page with iframe]

Code in [child website](http://jsfiddle.net/br3g0vmd/1):

```
    //Get the users message from the message input box
    var message = document.getElementById("message").value;

    //Check that the message is not blank
    if (message !== "") {
    parent.postMessage(message, '*');
    }
    else {
         alert("You cannot send a blank message!");   
    }
}
```

Code in [parent website](https://codepen.io/Megahra/pen/yLYWzab):

```
function receiver(message) {
    console.log(message); // This never appears in the console, even when a message is added to innerHtml
    //get the message container html element (in this case, the messages div)
    var messagecontainer = document.getElementById('messages');
    var trusteddomain = 'http://fiddle.jshell.net';

    //Get the time of message receipt
    var currenttime = new Date();
    //format the time into a user readable format
    var formattedtime = currenttime.getHours() + ':' + currenttime.getMinutes() + ':' + currenttime.getSeconds();

    //inspect the origin property of the message event to ensure the message originates from the same domain)
    if (message.origin == 'http://fiddle.jshell.net') {
        if (message.data[0] != 'embed') {
            var msgcontent = message.data;
            messagecontainer.innerHTML += 'message received @ ' + formattedtime + ': ' + msgcontent + '<br />';
        }
    }
}

//Add an event listener to the window object to catch any message events
window.addEventListener('message', receiver, false);
```